# Cannot export a fusionchart with 'Embedding Charts Using <OBJECT>/<EMBED> Tags'

Tags: pdf, export, embed, fusioncharts

I am trying to export a fusion chart created using 'Embedding Charts Using / Tags'.

Export works just perfect with the right click (on the chart) and chose a pdf to export.
But I am not able to make this work via javascript. I have a button outside the chart which upon clicking calls the function below

```
function myexport()
{
 var cObject = getChartFromId('Column3D');
        if( cObject.hasRendered() ) cObject.exportChart({exportFormat: 'PDF'});
}
```

the object above returned is null and this fails on the next line

here is the full prototype

```
<html>
 <head>
<title>My Chart</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusionCharts.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fusionChartsExportComponent.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ExportMyChart() {
        var cObject = getChartFromId('Column3D');
        if( cObject.hasRendered() ) cObject.exportChart({exportFormat: 'PDF'});
 }
</script>
  </head>
  <body>
     <object width="400" height="400" id="Column3D" classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000"    codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=8,0,0,0" >         
<param name="testname" value="Column3D.swf" />         
<param name="FlashVars" value="&dataURL=testData.xml&chartWidth=400&chartHeight=300&DOMId=myChart1&registerWithJS=1&debugMode=0">
<param name="quality" value="high" />         
<embed src="Column3D.swf" 
    flashVars="&dataURL=testData.xml&chartWidth=400&chartHeight=300&DOMId=myChart1&registerWithJS=1&debugMode=0"
    width="400" height="300" name="Column3D" quality="high" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"    pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" />      
</object>

<!-- We also create a DIV to contain the FusionCharts client-side exporter component -->
<div id="holderDiv" align="center">FusionCharts Export Handler Component</div>
<script type="text/javascript">

 var myExportComponent = new FusionChartsExportObject("testExporter1", "FCExporter.swf");

//Render the exporter SWF in our DIV fcexpDiv
myExportComponent.Render("holderDiv");
</script>
<input type="button" value="Export My Chart" onclick="ExportMyChart()" />
```

Answer (score 0):

found the answer for this on fusion charts forum. Looks like there is an issue with the export when both embed and object tag are used in the browser for the chart.

Workaround for this one was explained 
[here](http://forum.fusioncharts.com/topic/8131-export-issue-when-initiating-export-via-javascript/page__gopid__32756#entry32756)

Answer (score 0):

Please find the modified code below:

My Chart

function ExportMyChart() 
{ 


 var cObject = document.getElementById('Column3D'); 

 if( cObject.hasRendered && cObject.hasRendered())
 cObject.exportChart({exportFormat: 'PDF'}); 
}

FusionCharts Export Handler Component 

 
var myExportComponent = new FusionChartsExportObject("fcExporter1", "../../FusionCharts/FCExporter.swf"); 

myExportComponent.Render("holderDiv");

Hope this helps.